# Apex Test Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

1. Hi Team, Could you please help me to get coverage above 75%.v it's
   covered 65% now.it's covered before contact.

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class CreateNewIndividualAccountApexController {


    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, String> getLabels(){
        return CommonUtility.getFieldLabels(Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe());
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, String> getHelpText(){
        return CommonUtility.getFieldMetaData(Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe());
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveAccount(Account account, String businessAccountId, Operating_Name__c legalName){
        SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
        String accountId = null;
        try{
            account.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(Label.Account_RecordType_Individual).getRecordTypeId();

            //logic to concatenate first name, middle name and last name
            String name = UtilConstantForCRM.BLANK;
            name += legalName.First_Name__c + UtilConstantForCRM.SPACE;
            if(String.isNotBlank(legalName.Middle_Name__c)){
                name += legalName.Middle_Name__c + UtilConstantForCRM.SPACE;
            }
            name += legalName.Last_Name__c;

            account.Salutation__c = legalName.Salutation__c;
            account.First_Name__c = legalName.First_Name__c;
            account.Middle_Name__c = legalName.Middle_Name__c;
            account.Last_Name__c = legalName.Last_Name__c;
            account.Name = name;
            Database.SaveResult accountSaveResult = Database.insert(account, false);
            system.debug('accssaveresult-->' +accountSaveResult);
            accountId = accountSaveResult.getId();
            if(accountSaveResult.isSuccess()){
                system.debug('accssaveresultsuccess-->' +accountSaveResult.isSuccess());
                    //creating legal name on successful creation of account
                    //JM legalName.Name = name;
                    legalName.Name__c = name;
                    legalName.Primary__c = true;
                    legalName.Type__c = Label.Legal_Name_Type;
                    legalName.Profile__c = accountId;
                    insert legalName;

                    List<LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c> connectionRoleList = [Select Id from LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c
where Name = :label.Connection_Role_Contact];
                    if(!connectionRoleList.isEmpty()){
                        LLC_BI__Connection__c connection = new LLC_BI__Connection__c();
                        connection.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c = accountSaveResult.getId();
                        connection.LLC_BI__Connected_From__c = businessAccountId;
                        connection.Relationship_Status__c = Label.Connection_Status_Active;
                        connection.LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c = connectionRoleList.get(0).Id;
                        insert connection;
                        system.debug('connectioninsert-->' +connection);

                        //inserting new contact associated to individual account
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        system.debug('contactinsert-->' +contact);
                        contact.salutation = legalName.Salutation__c;
                        contact.firstName = legalName.First_Name__c;
                        contact.middleName = legalName.Middle_Name__c;
                        contact.lastName = legalName.Last_Name__c;
                        contact.accountId = accountId;
                        Database.SaveResult contactSaveResult = Database.insert(contact, false);
                        if(contactSaveResult.isSuccess()){
                            AccountContactRelation accountContactBusiness = new AccountContactRelation();
                            accountContactBusiness.accountId = businessAccountId;
                            accountContactBusiness.contactId = contactSaveResult.getId();
                            accountContactBusiness.isActive = true;
                            insert accountContactBusiness;

                        }else{
                            Database.rollback(sp);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }else{
                        Database.rollback(sp);
                        return null;
                    }
                }else{
                    Database.rollback(sp);
                    return null;
                }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Database.rollback(sp);
            return null;
        }
        return accountId;
    }
     }
```

Apex Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class CreateNewIndividualAccountApex_Test{
    static testMethod void runPositiveTestCases() {
        List<Account> acclist = new List<Account>();
        String IndrecordTypeId =  Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Individual').getRecordTypeId();
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.Preferred_Language__c='EN';
        ac.Salutation__c = 'Mr.';
        ac.Middle_Name__c = 'test1';
        ac.Last_Name__c='lstname';
        ac.RecordTypeId = IndrecordTypeId;
        ac.Name='SFNTesting';

        Operating_Name__c IndOppName = new Operating_Name__c();
        IndOppName.Profile__c = ac.Id;
        IndOppName.Type__c = 'LGLNAME';
        IndOppName.Middle_Name__c = 'testmidname';
        IndOppName.Name__c ='Contact'; 

        List<LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c> corolelist1 = new List<LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c>();
        LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c corole1 = new LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c();
        corole1.Name = 'Contact';
        corole1.LLC_BI__Sort_Order__c = 2;
        corole1.LLC_BI__Role_Type__c = 'Individual';
        corolelist1.add(corole1);
        insert corolelist1;
        system.assertEquals('Contact', corole1.Name);

        LLC_BI__Connection__c connection = new LLC_BI__Connection__c();
        connection.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c = ac.id;
        connection.LLC_BI__Connected_From__c = ac.id;
        connection.Relationship_Status__c = 'Active';
        connection.LLC_BI__Connection_Role__c =  corolelist1[0].Id;
        //insert connection;

        Contact cc = new Contact();
        cc.AccountId = ac.Id;
        cc.LastName = 'testname';
        cc.salutation = 'Mr.';
        cc.firstName = 'SFN';
        cc.middleName = 'Test';

        Test.startTest();
        new CreateNewIndividualAccountApexController();
        CreateNewIndividualAccountApexController.saveAccount(ac,ac.id,IndOppName);
        CreateNewIndividualAccountApexController.getLabels();
        CreateNewIndividualAccountApexController.getHelpText();
        Test.stopTest();
    } }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are best placed to do this work. Look at the uncovered lines via the Developer Console and create additional tests to create the conditions to execute the uncovered lines. You are likely to need to factor out common code into utility methods in the test class that you then call from the multiple `testMethod` methods.

It looks like you are missing the fundamental point of tests: the tests should confirm the behaviour of the code being tested by using **asserts**. If you aim to do that in your tests the coverage will be achieved as a side effect.

Comment: up to insert connection; is covered. after from Contact till accountContactBusiness is not covered. I have inserted system.assertEquals after the contact insertion. Could anyone please suggest me the way?

Comment: @Chaitu Check the `if` or whatever condition immediately before the first uncovered line and make sure you have a test that sets up the data in such a way that the code branch is entered.